# UITableView inside a UIView

Tags: ios, xcode

I would put an `UITableView` inside  a `UIView`. I created a XIB where I have a tableView.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface PointsViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate>
{

  IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
}
@end

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

 [super viewDidLoad];
 [tableView setDelegate:self];
}
```

I instantiate the `PointViewController` class from another class and add it to a `UINavigationBar` by means of a button:when I click the button, the `PointsViewController`'view (the tableView) shall open. But it does not.
What am I missing? I tried also to make PointsViewController as a subclass of `UITableViewController` which works, but no `UITableView` is displayed.

Comment: are you unable to push the `PointsViewController` or you can not see the `UITableView` content?, besides the `UITableViewDelegate` protocol you should also implement the `UITableViewDataSource`.

Comment: I cannot see the UITableView...

Comment: can you add to the code the implementation of the methods from `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` protocol?, the problem could be there

Comment: You are adding UITableView in .xib are Programatically

Answer (score 2):

You will also need to make your ViewController a delegate for UITableViewDataSource.

```
@interface PointsViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
{
    IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
}
@end
```

...and support the corresponding methods.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: I added the protocol, but the problem remains. The view does not load, or rather does not appear.

Comment: Did you connect the tableView IBOutlet to the table in the XIB? You should also use breakpoints or NSLog diagnostics to see if the delegate methods are being called?

Comment: Are the delegate methods being called?

Comment: Strangely not. I put an NSLog in every delegate of PointsViewController. However, I also change the main class to UITableViewController. Same result. No message in delegate and nothing showing. Could someone provide a minimal working example? Click on a button and display a UITableView.

Comment: Did you connect up your view from file owner to the view that the tableview is nested in? Also when you init, use initWithNibName:@"<nibname>"

Answer (score 1):

You need to also hook up the table's dataSource and delegate to the File's Owner.  Otherwise the view controller doesn't know what table to send responses to.

In your XIB, select the table and open the Connection Inspector.  Then drag the 'plus' sign next to dataSource to File's Owner to make the connection.  Do the same for delegate and the table's referencing outlet.